# Send a file to ASP.NET MVC Controller via HttpClient get wierd name (=?utf-8?B?U...)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, httpclient

When the filename has special chars I am receiving a wierd file name on Request.Files[0].FileName. Something like "=?utf-8?B?U..."

To send the file I am doing:

```
ProgressMessageHandler progress = new ProgressMessageHandler();
progress.HttpSendProgress += OnHttpSendProgress;

HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(progress);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = true;

MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var fileContent = new StreamContent(new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open));
content.Add(fileContent, "file", fileInfo.Name);

HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage();
message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
message.Content = content;
message.RequestUri = uri;

var resultado = await client.SendAsync(message, CancellationToken);
```

What Am I doing wrong?

I am using WebClient for while:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.UploadProgressChanged += OnHttpSendProgress;
await client.UploadFileTaskAsync(uriBuilder.Uri, "POST", fileInfo.FullName);
```